# How to make connectors in highcharts horizontal

Tags: highcharts

Hi i have kept the code in below path `http://jsfiddle.net/kea77o7j/`

I need the connectors to be in horizontally straight not in different shape like the following

```
'http://jsfiddle.net/49hq2sm4/'
```

Someone please help me i tried many times but no success

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you paste a mockup how it should be printed? Because in your scenario Multi-class and Other labels will not have a connections (horizontally not stick with pie)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bfvop.png this is the image url please check

Comment: Defaulty in the highcharts we have a soft/nonsoft connects, but you can disable connectors and use [renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path) to add horizontal paths.